# shopping cart in php for Windows Azure

Tags: php, azure, responsive-design, shopping-cart

Is there any shopping cart built in php that can be run on Windows Azure.
I don't know about the Azure cloud. please help

IF there are many then I would prefer the one with responsive layout.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you only require a database (SQL Server or MySQL) you can likely take any PHP shopping cart.

Comment: will it work in Windows Azure?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a first class citizen when it concerns Windows Azure. Take a look at the [PHP development center](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/) for more information.

Nowadays you have the possibility to either choose for SQL Azure or to run MySQL on a dedicated IaaS platform offering or you can even run it with Windows Azure Websites: [Create and deploy a PHP-MySQL Windows Azure Website using WebMatrix](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-w-mysql-and-webmatrix/).

So if you have a PHP based shopping cart that runs on MySQL you should also be able to run it on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I want to clarify some things, becasue there is missleading information. First of all, and all correct - PHP is indeed first class citizen in Windows Azure. But from then on, there are two approaches:

- [Windows Azure Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/cloud-services/) (a.k.a. WebRole and everything mentioned in the [PHP Development Center](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/))
- [Windows Azure WebSite](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/) (a.k.a. Azure WebSites)

Taking the cloud services approach none existing PHP shopping cart can be run without modifications. Because the Cloud Services are PaaS offering, with a **stateless** roles. (you can learn more on terminlogy - i.e. cloud service / role / role instance, from [my blog post here](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/12/windows-azure-basics-part-1-of-n.html) - it all concerns PaaS and Cloud Service). If you chose Cloud Service - take *any* existing PHP shopping cart and begin modifying it - from how it stores Session, to how it writes and reads files to persistent storage.

Taking the Windows Azure WebSites approach - you can literally take any existing PHP Shopping cart and run it in Windows Azure WebSite. You can either do it so, or chose some of the gallery - you can install for example WordPress with couple of clicks and then add some [shopping cart plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/shopping-cart). You can do the same with [Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart), or even [Drupal](http://www.ubercart.org/).

All of them are supported from within the website gallery in Windows Azure WebSites. Once installed you can customize them.

One thing to note is that Windows Azure Websites is currently in preview, so there is no SLA for it, and no commercial projects are supported to run on WAWS.